# What is the difference between x 509 certificate and X509CertificateHolder in Java?

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

So i have a problem, i cant´t understand the difference between x509certificate and X509CertificateHolder java, because there are not who explain, of correct form, everybody do code but, they are not specific, what do in those lines, and the documentation is a little hard to understand, if someone can help me, i'll be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: `X509CertificateHolder` is from BouncyCastle library and `X509Certificate` comes from JDK ?

Comment: and so what is t better?? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In here  , I think this will be enough to understand it very easily**

Actually `X509Certificate` certificate contains information about the identity to which a certificate is issued and the identity that issued it. Standard information in an `X509Certificate` certificate includes

Actually `X509CertificateHolder` bouncycastle Document  is saying ,  It is  Holding class for an `X509Certificate` structure.

[bouncycastle DOC](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder.html)

Comment: thank you very much, for your help, I was a little confused, but now can understand, thanks to you.